# Copy ResourceStream In Stream

Tags: delphi, stream, filestreams, tstream

I need help in this code

This is all code

Request: TIdHTTPRequestInfo

Response: TIdHTTPResponseInfo

JQuery: TResourceStream

```
procedure TServer.ActiveServer;
begin
  DefaultPort := 8117;
  Active := True;
  OnCommandGet := FServerCommandGet;
  JQuery := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'JQuery',RT_RCDATA);
end;

function TServer.FindFiles: Boolean;
var
  Stream : TStream;
begin
  if Request.Document = '/jquery.js' then
  begin
    Response.ContentType := 'application/x-javascript';
    Stream := TStream.Create;
    Stream.Position := 0;
    Stream.CopyFrom(JQuery,JQuery.Size);
    Response.ContentStream := Stream;
    Result := True;
  end else
    Result := False;
end;
```

error : TStream.Seek not implemented

The problem is in the copy TResourceStream in TStream

Comment: The same problem

Comment: Request: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
Response: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
JQuery: TResourceStream;

Comment: We cant see how JQuery has been created, please provide full code

Comment: JQuery := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'JQuery',RT_RCDATA);

Comment: JQuery is JQuery.JS

Comment: Please do not add code in comments but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48206083/edit) your question and provide a full code sample that exposes the problem. Since you are new here, please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

[`TStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream) is an abstract class so it cannot be used directly, you must use one it's descendants. [`TResourceStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TResourceStream) for example.

P.S : I see that you are dealing with Indy, no need to free the stream when assigned to `ContentStream`, Indy will handle that for you.

```
function TServer.FindFiles: Boolean;
var
  Stream : TResourceStream;
begin
  if Request.Document = '/jquery.js' then
  begin
    Response.ContentType := 'application/x-javascript';
    Response.ContentStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'JQuery', RT_RCDATA);
    Result := True;
  end else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There's also a [TResourceStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TResourceStream)

Comment: The same problem

Comment: JQuery: TResourceStream

Comment: JQuery := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'JQuery',RT_RCDATA);

Comment: I'm not good in English language

Comment: The editor asked me to add more details

Comment: I would even `Response.ContentStream:=TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'JQuery',RT_RDCATA);`

Comment: thanks this is the solution

Comment: @whosrdaddy The code shown in your answer is all wrong. `TResourceStream` does not have a parameterless constructor, and it is read-only, so calling `CopyFrom()` on it is an invalid operation. Change `TResourceStream` to `TMemoryStream` and then the code will be *almost* "correct" (you would need to seek `JQuery.Position` instead of `Stream.Position`), but will not be thread-safe (`JQuery` only has 1 `Position`), as you can't copy `JQuery` in multiple HTTP requests simultaneously without synchronizing access to it. Best to create a new `TResourceStream` on each request, like Stijn showed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes that is correct, changed accordingly